# How to access the value of one variable set from a function from another function

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I am making a minecraftpe mod and I have to access the value of something which is set in another (because using setTile in java functions crashes the game as x, y, z are only defined in the useItem template.) So I needed to do this basically here is the function I am using...

```
var ctx = com.mojang.minecraftpe.MainActivity.currentMainActivity.get();
var seekerProgress = 0;
function newLevel()
{
    run: function()
    {
        try
        {
            var modWindow = new android.widget.PopupWindow();
            var modLayout = new  android.widget.LinearLayout(ctx);
            var seeker = new android.widget.SeekBar(ctx);
            seeker.setProgress(seekerProgress);
            seeker.setMax(1);
            modLayout.addView(seeker);
            modWindow.setContentView(modLayout);
            modWindow.setHeight(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            modWindow.setWidth(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            modWindow.showAtLocation(ctx.getWindow().getDecorView(), android.view.Gravity.CENTER | android.view.Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                onStopTrackingTouch: function()
                {
                    seekerProgress = seeker.getProgress();
                    if (seekerProgress === 1)
                    {
                        print(target);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
function modFunction()
{
    var target = 0; //I want this value to be accessible in the newLevel function
}
```

What can I do to aide this?

Comment: Sorry for the quick lazy code. Usually I put way more into it by making it a menu and utilizing all of what java has to offer but this is just a quick example.

Comment: Use window.target = 0 to make it global maybe?

Comment: This actually does not work in a browser. It is a js script that is loaded in an application called BlockLauncher pro which mods a game called Minecraft PE I also did try to make a global function by creating the variable outside all functions. Then assigning the value in one and access it but it returns null and doesnt pick up

Comment: @jfriend00 it is a js file but I used java (rhino) so I tagged both. Rhino is java in javascript

Comment: @jfriend00 Rhino is java... >~< this is a legit language if you dont know what it is then thats fine. Dont speak for anyone else. Rhino is java in javascript

Comment: @jfriend00 thats why I tagged all three rhino, java, javascript. Java because I am using java resources javascript because I am using javascript variables and such and rhino (because its rhino I guess)

Comment: If you need anymore info just let me know